# Dockerfile entrypoint script arguments in docker run

Tags: linux, unix, docker, dockerfile, devops

My Dockerfile contains a

```
RUN xyz.sh --IP localhost
```

and when I give the command docker run I want to insert a new IP address:

```
docker run -it IP 127.0.0.1 name:tag
```

How to pass it like this?

I tried to give ENV in Docker file and using -e in run command but nothing works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RUN` instructions happen at build time.

`ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` instructions happen at run time.

You probably want something like this in your Dockerfile:

```
....
ENTRYPOINT ["xyz.sh"]

CMD ["--IP", "127.0.0.1"]
....
```

Then you can run with:

`docker run -it some-image --IP 127.0.0.1`

Arguments after the image overwrite the `CMD` instruction so then it runs the `ENTRYPOINT` instruction followed by your arguments.

Comment: Hi I am getting an error - unknown instruction : ENTRYPOINT while building the image

Comment: Post your full Dockerfile please and the output of `docker info`.

Comment: please check the question I added my actual Dockerfile